# Determining what event will be emitted

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, events, static-call

I want to call a contract function `f()` using ethers, but before I do so, I want to make sure that it executes in the desired way.

I can learn whether `f()` executes in the desired way by looking at the event that is emitted when the function is called. However, I do not see any way to obtain this event using the static call interface ethers provides.

Typechain tells me that the type of `myContract.callStatic.f` is `([...], overrides?: ethers.CallOverrides | undefined): Promise<void>`. When the function is actually called, it does have a return value contrary to the type determined by typechain, but the return value always seems to be an empty array (which might be because `f()` does not return anything), i.e. no would-be-emitted events present.

Is there a way of static-calling `f()` that will return the events that would be emitted?

Comment: No, you will need to subscribe to the event to check if its emits after making the call, but the function call will not return an event.

Comment: @JulissaDC On a regular call, a function `wait()` is returned. Evaluating this function yields a tx receipt that contains the events that were emitted. I was hoping for similar behavior. That's why I was checking the return value. Anyway, how can I subscribe to events emitted in static calls?